# JUnit5 (Vintage) initializationError while using @ParameterizedTest and @RunWith(Parameterized.class)

Tags: mockito, junit5, parameterized

I stumble across an initializationError while I am trying to use the parameterized feature of JUnit 5.

```java
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class ServiceTest {

    @InjectMocks
    Service service;

    private static Stream<Arguments> getArguments() {
        return Stream.of(
                Arguments.of("something", "result1", "result2"),
                Arguments.of("another", "result3", "result4")
        );
    }

    @ParameterizedTest
    @MethodSource("getArguments")
    @DisplayName("Test parseEndpoint method")
    void testMethod(String arg1, String result1, String result2) {

        final String[] strings = service.doSomething(arg1);

        assertEquals(result1, strings[0]);
        assertEquals(result2, strings[1]);
    }

}
```

Then I can see that my test is being run by the Parameterized engine and the JUnit Vintage unit. The thing here is how to disable class like this to be run only by the Parameterized.class?!

Answer (score 12):

You are mixing JUnit 4 and 5 in the same class.

Remove @RunWith(Parameterized.class), you do not need it. Remove all other code that comes from junit 4 packages, if there is such.

Your test will be fine after that.